# What's written on this bookmark?

Tags: translation, meaning

My friend sent me an image of a bookmark and I wish I knew what it said. If anyone can help me out, that would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says 「竹{たけ}しおり」, which literally means "bamboo bookmark".